# Libcontainer VS. LXC driver

Tags: docker, drivers, lxc

What are main differences between these `Docker` drivers? Why is `libcontainer` better than `LXC` driver? Why should we use `libcontainer`, which are its benefits on practical way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libcontainer is built into the code of Docker and clearly their favored choice.

Using a built-in library reduces dependencies and other moving parts, so it should be faster and can be considered more stable.

All is explained in more detail in the [Docker Blog](https://blog.docker.com/2014/03/docker-0-9-introducing-execution-drivers-and-libcontainer/).